# strtok: getting the value before the delimiter and not just the one after

Tags: c, strtok

I'm trying to split up a string into different parts in C. In C#, I just used `split()`, which created an array to access each part of the split string easily. Now in C I'm trying to split up strings like this: `"STXS1-21|S2-23ETX"`. I want to get the numbers 21 and 23 alone. If I were to `strtok` with the delimiter string of `"STX-|ETX"`, by my knowledge I'd get:

1. `S1-21|S2-23ETX`
2. `21|S2-23ETX`
3. `S2-23ETX`
4. `23ETX`

Im trying to get the numbers 21 and 23 alone though, so how would i accomplish that?

Comment: For starters, better refresh your knowledge of `strtok` by reading [its description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). Why not write a full custom function, though? It seems you are only interested in all digits that follow a `-`.

Comment: Do you have to use `strtok`? This might actually be a case where regular expressions are the better option.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "STXS1-21|S2-23ETX";
    char *sptr = str;
    while (sptr = strchr(sptr, '-'))
        printf("%d\n", atoi(++sptr));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
21
23
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide your code, I've had to guess that it is

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "STXS1-21|S2-23ETX";
    const char *d = "-|ESTX";
    char *p;

    for (p = strtok(s, d);  p;  p = strtok(NULL, d))
        puts(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, when you run it, you get

```
1
21
2
23
```

for the four numerals in your input string.  If these are predictably always there, just skip over them.

Remember the warnings in the `strtok` man page:

> #### BUGS
>
> Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:
>
> - These functions modify their first argument.
> - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.
> - The identity of the delimiting byte is lost.
> - The `strtok()` function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe.  Use `strtok_r()` if this matters to you.